# Chrome.storage.sync usage before page starts to add DOM elements

Tags: javascript, browser-cache, mutation-observers, google-chrome-storage

I am making an extension for university site, which i have no back-end access to. The task is to reorganize certain block elements, for which im trying to store information about in the string with numbers (elements are added into this string after the page loads). It worked well with `localStorage`, but ultimately there was a problem - each time the site admins update the site, the cache get cleared and the data is lost, so i choose to move to `chrome.storage` API.

Now, here is the problem. The behavior of `chrome.storage.sync.get` is rather incosistent, it might be slow enough to not get any data in the cache in time for `MutationObserver` to start working. I understand `chrome.storage.sync.get` is a asynchronous callback, but have no way to force it to work before the page starts getting filled.

```js
window.toDelete = [];

chrome.storage.sync.get('course', function(entries){
    window.toDelete = deserializeEntries(entries.course);
    console.log("hello");
})

// Mutation observer declaration and .observe call
```

In this example it might go either way, "hello" being printed before or after `MutationObserver` does all the work. I have a call that prints the contents of `toDelete` in `MutationObserver` to tell if it works with properly filled cache or not. [Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3G5YA.png) [Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RP8xR.png)

Comment: `chrome.storage` is extremely slow. Instead, send a message to your background script which will respond with the data. Alternatively, hide the elements using CSS selectors in a css file that you can inject via executeScript with `runAt: 'document_start'`.

Comment: @wOxxOm Yeah i don't exectly want to hide elements, since i want for things to look and work buttery smooth (already tried this method). I will try the background script, thank you.

Comment: Hiding should be fine if it's possible to create unique CSS selectors. BTW make sure your content script has `"run_at": "document_start"`